# Python Turtle module writing doesn't show up on screen

Tags: python

I am looking to create a starting screen for a simple game, this is the StartingScreen class (in starting_screen.py):

```
from turtle import Turtle

class StartingScreen(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.penup()
        self.color("white")
        self.hideturtle()
        self.write(arg="First to 5 wins!", align="center", font=("Courier", 25, "normal"))
```

And this is where I call it:

```
from turtle import Screen
from starting_screen import StartingScreen
screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.title("Pong Game")
starting_screen = StartingScreen
screen.exitonclick()
```

However when I run it all I get is an empty black screen. Any ideas on how to make it show up?

I have tried just creating a simple turtle and writing with that, which works, but I would like to get it working with it's own class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add parentheses `starting_screen = StartingScreen`.

it should we like this

```py
starting_screen = StartingScreen()
```

[image]